# create list from os command python

Tags: python

I'm trying to store content of `file.txt` into list

```
cat file.txt
dm-3
dm-5
dm-4
dm-2
```

here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import json
drives = os.system("cat file.txt")
for i in drives:
  print(i)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./lld-disks2.py", line 5, in <module>
    for i in drives:
  TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return of command output, use `popen` instead `os.system`.

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(["cat", "file.txt"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
print "output:", out
```

But I think @Fejs's answer is better.

Answer (score 2):

`os.system` returns the exit status-code of the command, not its output.

Instead, you should use Python built-in [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#open):

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
     list_of_lines = f.readlines()
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system):

> `os.system(command)`
>   Execute the command (a string) in a subshell. This is implemented by calling the Standard C function system(), and has the same limitations. Changes to sys.stdin, etc. are not reflected in the environment of the executed command.
>
> **On Unix, the return value is the exit status** of the process encoded in the format specified for wait(). Note that POSIX does not specify the meaning of the return value of the C system() function, so the return value of the Python function is system-dependent.

You should probably just `open` the file and `readlines()`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list-with-python) SO question perfectly demonstrates this.

Answer (score 1):

`os.system` returns exit status as integer, so that's why You get this error. Instead of using `os.system`, I suggest You read file using `open` command.
Something like this:

```
input_file = open(filename)
for line in input_file.readlines():
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `os.system` function does not return the output of the command you run, but an exit code. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system):

> the return value is the exit status of the process

If you want to get the content of a file, use `open` and `close` instead.